# How to return list in Dart language

Tags: json, dart

I my code I want to return categories name list and populate in list view by using dart. i use HTTP get request and can successfully print the Json data but when I loop the json data into list but it cannot and print(categoriesList.length); give me no result. any idea how to solve it

```
Future<List<Categories>> _getCategory() async {
var data = await http.get("https://thegreen.studio/ecommerce/E-CommerceAPI/E-CommerceAPI/AI_API_SERVER/Api/Category/ViewCategoryNameAPI.php");
var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
print(jsonData);

List<Categories> categoriesList = [];

for(var c in jsonData)
  {
    Categories a = Categories(c["Name"]);
    categoriesList.add(a);
  }

print(categoriesList.length);
return categoriesList;
```

}

Comment: can you add sample json data? which you received in jsonData

Comment: {body: [{Name: food}, {Name: grocery}, {Name: sports}]}

Comment: On which variable "data" or "jsonData" you receive the above JSON?

Comment: "jsonData" @ChandrasekarKesavan

Comment: so then try this "for(var c in jsonData.body)"

Comment: already use jsonData.body but still now showing

Comment: Can you try this one? jsonData.body.forEach((c) {
   print(c.Name);
 });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225962/discussion-between-riyal-and-chandrasekar-kesavan).

Comment: Try `for(var c in jsonData["body"])`. If the JS output above is correct, this is what you need to get to the list that you want to iterate.